# Getting a 500 internal server error thanks to some javascript in symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony

This is the code:

Controller:

```
public function isreadAction(Request $request) {

        var_dump($request->get('sentValue'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $pm = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
                ->findBypmid($request->get('sentValue'));

        $pm->setIsRead(true);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response();
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pmcontents").hide();
    $(".pmbox").click(function () {
        $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
        $(this).next().toggle();
        var myValue = $('this').attr('id');
        var DATA = 'sentValue=' + myValue;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('isread'),
            data: DATA,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("database has been updated");

            }
        });
    });

});
```

Routing:

```
isread:
    path:   /game/isread
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:isread }
    requirements:
    options:
        expose: true
```

If i click on the error it says that the variable is undefined:

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencodedNiet sorteren
sentValue   undefined
Bron
sentValue=undefined
```

What is the problem? I have tried some things and it seems that the problem lies within the ajax part of the javascript, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
    var myValue = $('this').attr('id'); //<- notice quote around this
```

with

```
    var myValue = $(this).attr('id');
```